# Using Perl how to read in a file and parse through logs to find error logs and output to a log.txt file

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to use Perl to create a program that will read in data for a file that is 40,000+ lines long and parse through each message to extract the error messages from it.

A sample of the data I am using looks like this:

```
--------All Messages---------
SUCCESS: data transferred successfully .
SUCCESS: data transferred successfully .
SUCCESS: data transferred successfully .
ERROR: there was an error transferring data .
SUCCESS: data transferred successfully .
SUCCESS: data transferred successfully .
SUCCESS: data transferred successfully .
ERROR: there was an error transferring the data and the error message spans
more than 1 line of code and may also contain newline characters as well .
SUCCESS: data transferred successfully .
SUCCESS: data transferred successfully .
SUCCESS: data transferred successfully .
---------END REPOSITORY---------
```

each message in the log has the following in common:

1) it starts with either SUCCESS or ERROR depending on the outcome

2) all messages will end with `<whitespace><period><newline>`

The following is code that I have written but for some reason I can't seem to debug it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
open(FH,$filetoparse);
{
# following line is supposed to change the delimiter for the file
    $/ = " .";
# the follow statement will create an error log of all error messages in log and save it
# to a file named errorlog.txt
    while(<FH>)
    {
        push (@msgarray, $_);
    }
if ($outputtype == 1)
{
    $outputfile="errorlog.txt";
    open(OUTPUT,">>$outputfile");
    $errorcount=0;
    $errortarget="ERROR";
    print OUTPUT "-----------Error Log-----------\n";

    for ($i=0;$i<@msgarray;$i++)
    {
    if ($msgarray[$i] =~ /^$errortarget/)
    {

        print OUTPUT "$msgarray[$i]\n";
#       print OUTPUT "next code is: \n";
        $errorcount++;

    }
    print OUTPUT "\nError Count : $errorcount\n";

    close (OUTPUT);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is a 40k lines file, why do you want to read it up all in memory?

Comment: At a guess I would say your code will work if you change your test to `$msgarray[$i] =~ /^$errortarget/m` which will allow the `^` to match after the leading newline on your records

Comment: Please don't fix your code after posting it. It puts other people's comments and solutions out of context

Comment: gotcha. sorry Borodin, still relatively new to using this site. I'll follow SOP better going forward.

Answer (score 3):

Add the newline character to your delimiter.  Change:

```
$/ = " .";
```

to:

```
$/ = " .\n";
```

And if you want to remove the delimiter, you can `chomp`.

```
while(<FH>)
{
    chomp;
    push (@msgarray, $_);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with setting `$/ = " ."` is that the lines you read will end at that closing dot, and the following line will start with the newline character after it. That means none of your lines except possibly the first will start with `"ERROR"` - they will start with `"\nERROR"` instead, and so your test will always fail

There are some other issues with your code that you will want to understand.

- You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings`, and declare all your variables with `my` as close as possible to their first point of use
- You should always use lexical file handles with the three-parameter form of `open`. You also need to check the status of every `open` and put `$!` in the `die` string so that you know *why* it failed. So

  ```
  open(FH,$filetoparse);
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  open my $in_fh, '<', $filetoparse or die qq{Unable to open "$filetoparse" for input: $!};
  ```
- It is better to process text files line by line unless you have good reasons to read them into memory in their entirety — for instance, if you need to do multiple passes through the data, or if you need random access to the contents instead of processing them linearly.

  It's also worth noting that, instead of writing

  ```
  while ( <$in_fh> ) {
      push @msgarray, $_;
  }
  ```

  you can say just

  ```
  @msgarray = <$in_fh>;
  ```

  which has exactly the same result
- It is often better to iterate over the *contents* of an array rather than over its indices. So instead of

  ```
  for ( my $i = 0; $i < @msgarray; ++$i ) {
      # Do stuff with $msgarray[$i];
  }
  ```

  you could write

  ```
  for my $message ( @msgarray ) {
      # Do stuff with $message;
  }
  ```

Here's a rewrite of your code that demonstrates these points

```
open my $in_fh, '<', $filetoparse
        or die qq{Unable to open "$filetoparse" for input: $!};

{
    if ( $outputtype == 1 ) {

        my $outputfile  = 'errorlog.txt';
        my $errorcount  = 0;
        my $errortarget = 'ERROR';

        open my $out_fh, '>>', $outputfile
                or die qq{Unable to open "$outputfile" for output: $!};

        print $out_fh "-----------Error Log-----------\n";

        while ( <$in_fh> ) {
          next unless /^\Q$errortarget/;

          s/\s*\.\s*\z//;       # Remove trailing detail
          print $out_fh "$_\n";
          ++$errorcount;
        }

        print $out_fh "\nError Count : $errorcount\n";

        close ($out_fh) or die $!;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot! Would it be possible for you to tell me why my code isn't working (whether it be the specific line with an error or what?) I know my code is bad form (that's how I learned from an intro to perl course at local college), I am curious where my code is failing. Thanks if you can help!!

Comment: @Drubs1181: As I said a couple of times, the problem is that you have set `$/ = " ."` so each record has a newline at the *start*, and `/^ERROR/` doesn't match

Answer (score -1):

The file handle `OUTPUT` is closed within the `for` loop which you access for every iteration after closing. Move it outside the loop and try it

Comment: That isn't true. The `close` is outside both the `while` and the `for` loops